# How does the Built-in Bindings of Google Guice work?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice, binding

I tried Google Guice the first time and find it very nice.
But, when I reached the part of [Built-in Bindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BuiltInBindings) I do not understand the examples.

For me it looks like I can use it for logging like an interceptor, but I don't know how.

Could someone of you explain this type of Binding and how I can use it? And maybe (if it's possible) use it for logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the documentation indicates is that the `bind(Logger.class).to(...)` call has already been made for you.  Thus, you don't need to call the bind method.  Instead, you can inject it directly as if you had already called bind:

```
class DoSomething {
    private final Logger logger;
    @Inject public DoSomething(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get it from the injector:

```
/* even without specifying modules, logger is present */
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
Logger logger = injector.getInstance(Logger.class);
```

If you need to override the logger, then you'll have to [use this method](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=269).

Comment: Thank! Thats what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

All the example you point to is showing is that you don't have to provide a binding for Logger.class in code such as the example. Since the 99% case is

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ConsoleTransactionLog.class);
```

Guice will provide that logger for you as a convenience. If you need a different loggers (i.e., one not based on the class being injected into), you can provide your own binding.

Comment: Maybe its a little bit foolish but could I ask you how I use THIS variant? I only know it like this (with a factory):

private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(FrontLayer.class);
and than use it with
LOG.debug("bla");

Comment: I don't know which Logging package you're using. Guice supports "built-in" support for java.util.logging.Logger

If you're using a different logging package, you'll either need provide your own binding or somehow extend Guice.

Comment: I normal use Apache Commons Logging in combination with log4j.